# Cooling SMDs from the bottom

Tags: thermal, heatsink, interface

I remember a clever way to cool a SMD with a thermal pad from the bottom.

It's like a copper pin or a rivet that goes through the board, in a hole right under the SMD thermal pad. Then it has a flat top to mate with a heat sink.

[image]

I remember reading datasheets about this, but I can't find it! Anyone knows how it is called so I can search for it?

Comment: look for 'thermal vias'

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes I know about thermal vias, but that's not what I'm looking for. It's a copper lug with a small flat cross section (a few mm) that goes into the pcb, and a large flat interface to the heat sink...

Comment: Are you sure it has a special name? A copper bar should do IMO. It's like putting a large hole instead of placing a number of vias, and using a bar through that big hole to increase conductivity.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I found it, see my answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I wonder if this is something that a copper heat-pipe could be soldered to?  (Could they even withstand/be soldered? Perhaps thermal epoxy...)

Comment: There are also similar things called copper coins or copper inlays.

Comment: @LarsHankeln Indeed. What I like about this design is the threaded hole in the back. So there's no need to clamp the pcb with the flat copper coin on top of the heat sink. This thing does both thermal transfer and fastening...

Answer (score 8):

Finally found it. It was called "PowerPeg" but the company that sold it went out of business. Image from [datasheet](https://d3s5r33r268y59.cloudfront.net/datasheets/7790/2016-10-25-22-31-17/Design_Reference.pdf).

[image]

Comment: I would be a bit worried about the potential mechanical stress being added directly to the relatively delicate component. I would be interested to see a comparison between doing this and just having lots of thermal vias that go directly to the heatsink. My guess would be that this is a pretty niche application, only required for super high power dissipation ICs

Comment: This calculator (https://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/03/12/pcb-via-calculator/) suggests that a 14 mil via with 2oz copper through a 1.6mm PCB has about 40C/W conductivity, so in order to match this copper thing you would need about 20 of those, which is pretty straightforward and doesn't require an extra process and extra component like this does. You would still lose a little bit of conductivity at the heatsink/pcb interface, but I dont think it would be much if you add some thermal paste or a thermal pad. I would trust that much more than I would trust this, and its cheaper too.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's why they went out of business!

Comment: also solder is better than any thermal pastem so if you can solder the heatsink on that's a big win.

Comment: @Jasen are you aware of small heat sinks to solder on the bottom of the board? I've seen SMD heat sinks but they're all designed to straddle over a DPAK so the heat has to travel horizontally through the thin copper. Would work better if soldered on the back, right on top of the vias.